# create constant 2d array in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, multidimensional-array, nsstring, constants

Does anyone know how I might create a constant 2d-array in iOS/Ojective-c? In java it would be

```
public static final String MY_2D_ARRAY = {{"dog","cat","sheep"},{"bread","end","van"}};
```

The following is not working for me

```
extern NSString * const MY_2D_ARRAY[][]; //etc
```

Comment: @p4sh4 if it's a duplicate, do you mind writing the answer here? The link you provide does not address 2D arrays.

Comment: You can see my answer below. If you can't create a single-dimensional array as a constant, you obviously cannot create a two-dimensional one. Some answers to the other question describe how you can try to use a C array to do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since in ios you can't create constant array as you shown but you can use it as alternate

```
//  constants.h

+ (NSArray*) MY_2D_ARRAY;

//  constants.m

+ (NSArray*) MY_2D_ARRAY{ 

    static NSArray* arr = nil;

    if (arr == nil) {
        arr = @[@"a",@"b"]];
    }
    return arr;
}

// you can Use it where you required 

[constants MY_2D_ARRAY];
```

If this help you then you can accept it as solution.

Comment: you need to use dispatch_once to make it thread-safe

Comment: Why this answer is down voted ? If someone have any better suggestion then write their answer, so that will help us to understand the things.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C to create Array you need to use `NSArray(Immutable)`. Alternatively `NSMutableArray(mutable)`.

```
NSArray *arr = @[@[@"a", @"b"], @[@"c", @"d"]];
```

Comment: @{} is not for array. It's for dictionary.

Comment: Where in the code would I put that line? Because Xcode gives the error: `Initializer element is not a compile-time constant`

Comment: @learner Put it in Implementation section.

Comment: Yes. That's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how

```
NSArray *arr = @[
                 @[@"dog", @"cat", @"sheep"], 
                 @[@"bread", @"end", @"van"],
                  ...
                ];
```

Comment: Where in the code would I put that line? Because Xcode gives the error: `Initializer element is not a compile-time constant`

Comment: it would need to go inside a function that would run at the start of your app, you cant define it as an const/extern because when using the `@[]` notation, its not actually a constant, its shorthand for writing `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:x,y,z,nil];`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a constant NSArray, because as any Objective-C object (besides NSString), it is created at runtime and you cannot use an expression to initialise it. You should consider using some other approach, perhaps use a singleton.